# How to store multiple items purchased in a single transaction?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am new to MySQL.My database is retail product bought by customer or webview data. Example:

```
ID  Records
R1  {iphone5s,levis,Dell,Dior,amazon}
R2  {levis,Dell,amazon,Starbucks,google glass}
R3  {iphone5s,Dell,Dior,google glass}
R4  {iphone5s,levis,Starbucks}
R5  {iphone5s,levis,Dell,google glass}
```

I want to store this data into database.I store this data as:

```
ID    iphone5s   levis   Dell    Dior   amazon  Starbucks   google glass

R1       1         1      1        1       1         0          0

R2       0         1      1        0       1         1          1

R3       1         0      1        1       0         0          1

R4       1         1      0        0       0         1          0

R5       1         1      1        0       0         0          1


create table retail(ID varchar(50),
                    iphone5s int,
                    levis int,
                    Dell int,
                    Dior int,
                    amazon int,
                    Starbucks int,
                    googleglass int);

insert into retail
values ('r1',1,1,1,1,1,0,0), ('r2',0,1,1,0,1,1,1);

insert into retail
values ('r3',1,0,1,1,0,0,1),('r4',1,1,0,0,0,1,0),('r5',1,1,1,0,0,0,1);
```

Now I want to retrieve the ID which having iphone5s and store the ids. Similar I want collect ids having each columnname and store the corresponding id.

Using java I collect the column name by the following code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM retail");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 2; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
  String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
}
```

Now I want to select ID from retail `where columnname=1`.

Columnname should change every time.

Comment: it's called a Query Builder

Comment: @Drew what is meant by Query Builder?how  will it help in this case?

Comment: you dynamically build your query. One might be where colA='Jim', the next one could be quite different.

Comment: google How to Create a Java mysql Query Builder

Comment: I don't know MySQL well, but you can achieve this very simply with `UNPIVOT` and simple WHERE condition **[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9572f/4/0)**.  Feel free to translate to MySQL

Comment: As you loop through the rows in the ResultSetMetaData you can save the column names in a List, then iterate over the List to build a SELECT statement for each column name and retrieve the results in a regular ResultSet.

Comment: @Gord Thompson you are correct.This only i need.But how to write sql query..

Comment: @lad2025 Is UNPIVOT is available in mysql?

Comment: @lad2025 Is  any other better way to store the above original data in database system?so that i can manipulate easily.i want to check with each term (eg.iphone5s) in all rows and next i want to check the presence of combination of the terms(eg.iphone5s,Dell).

Comment: @SrividhyaShama - *"how to write sql query"* - You already know that; you have it in your question: `SELECT ID FROM retail WHERE columnname=1`. If you're asking about how to construct that string to include the column name text then `String.format()` can help you with that.

Comment: @GordThompson how to use java variable as a column name?If i store the column names in a list using java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From a comment to the question:*

> Is any other better way to store the above original data in database system?

Absolutely. You should store each item purchased in a separate row, like this:

```
ID  item
--  ------------
R1  iphone5s
R1  levis
R1  Dell
R1  Dior
R1  amazon
R2  levis
R2  Dell
R2  amazon
R2  Starbucks
R2  google glass
...
```

That makes it easier to query (because the column names are constant) and you won't have to alter your database structure if you ever need to add a new product. You could always "pivot" the data into the format you have now, but you shouldn't store it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` equivalent in MySQL. Now you can query simply using `WHERE brand = 'name' AND is_available = 1`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca64/5)**

```
create table retail(ID varchar(50),
                    iphone5s int,
                    levis int,
                    Dell int,
                    Dior int,
                    amazon int,
                    Starbucks int,
                    googleglass int);

insert into retail
values ('r1',1,1,1,1,1,0,0), ('r2',0,1,1,0,1,1,1),
       ('r3',1,0,1,1,0,0,1),('r4',1,1,0,0,0,1,0),('r5',1,1,1,0,0,0,1);

select id
from
(
  select
    t.id,
    c.brand,
    case c.brand
      when 'iphone5s'    then iphone5s
      when 'levis'       then levis
      when 'Dell'        then Dell
      when 'Dior'        then Dior
      when 'amazon'      then amazon
      when 'Starbucks'   then Starbucks
      when 'googleglass' then googleglass 
    end as is_available
  from retail t
  cross join
  (
    select 'iphone5s' as brand
    union all
    select 'levis'
    union all
    select 'Dell'
    union all
    select 'Dior'
    union all 
    select 'amazon'
    union all
    select 'Starbucks'
    union all
    select 'googleglass'
  ) c
) temp
where brand = 'iphone5s'   /* Here your brand/product_name */
  and is_available = 1
order by id;              /* If needed */
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo_UNPIVOT_TSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9572f/4/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, Brand, Val
  FROM
  (
     SELECT Id, iphone5s, levis, Dell, Dior, amazon, Starbucks, googleglass
     FROM retail
   ) t
   UNPIVOT
   (
     Val FOR Brand IN (iphone5s, levis, Dell,
                    Dior, amazon, Starbucks, googleglass)
    ) AS mrks
)
SELECT ID
FROM cte
WHERE Brand = 'Dior' 
AND [val] = 1;
```